# Swing JList - read and write XML from file

Tags: java, xml, swing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've looked at a few posts on this topic, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have an load method: The “Load” event should clear the right panel, and call your load() method. When load() is called, it should display the unmarshalled data in the right panel.

```
public void load() throws Exception {
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Configuration config = (Configuration) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("save.xml"));
    System.out.println(config.getComponent());
```

}

So, the question is how do you load the contents of an XML file into a JList ?

Here my Configuration.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "part"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Configuration")
public class Configuration {

    protected List<String> part;

    public List<String> getComponent() {
        if(part == null) {
            part = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.part;
    }
}
```

I have the save method to work correctly and below is my java code. Hope this help

```
public void load() throws Exception {

    }

    public void save() throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        File file = new File("save.xml");
        List<String> printList = config.getComponent();
        for(int i = 0;i < list.getSize();i++) {
            printList.add((String) list.getElementAt(i));
        }
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(config, file);
```

Comment: I think it's generally a good idea to have the title of your question refer to *your problem*.

Comment: @jan groth I'm supposed to write a program that is able to save the contents of one JList as an XML file and load that said file into another JList. I couldn't figure it out so I just made it print to the console

Comment: What's the XML look like?  What's the `Configuration` class look like?  Do you want the `Configuration` showen in the `JList` or the raw XML?  `JList` would be a poor choice for displaying raw XML. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @JamieSmith Please update your question rather then providing more information via comments. This will make it much easier for others to help you. And please change the title to something meaningful.

Comment: @jan groth Can you help me?

Comment: Only by changing the title to something more meaningful. Hopefully others are able to help.

Comment: I get the feeling that all you really need to know is how to populate a JList from a List.  Whether that List was created by unmarshalling XML seems to be irrelevant.

Comment: *"I've looked at a few posts on this topic,"* Which ones?  *"but none of the solutions have worked for me"* Why not?  --  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).